# Docker container keeps auto-restarting, I cannot figure out how to stop it?

Tags: docker, synology, home-assistant

I'm trying to do a clean install of home assistant on my docker, running on synology nas.
The problem is I had loads of old containers lying around, half of them probably not doing anything. I managed to delete all of them, except one.

It's called "hassio_supervisor"; and I cannot delete it. It keeps auto-restarting constantly, straining the CPU.

I tried the "force stop" "delete" path, but it auto restarts so fast I cannot delete it. I tried deleting the files, but it still keeps on auto restaring.
I tried SSH'ing and using "docker kill", "docker stop" etc, none of it stops it from restarting.

Each time it restarts, it gets a new ID. It restarts once per second or so.

[how it looks on command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9k3x.png)

Comment: Have you tried to stop it first with docker stop <container_hash>?

Comment: Hi by hash are you referring to the ID? If so yes - but then I get "no such container", probably because by the time I manage to copy paste the ID and type the command, it already restarted, and there by was assigned another ID

Comment: Try to do docker update --restart=no <container-name/containerId>

Comment: Then I get this: Cannot update container 26a6e3a041dea68f838eff33e1c820bae6afbbb217a269de32252d2168a8da7a: container is marked for removal and cannot be "update"

Comment: Are you running on windows or linux? We can try to delete the container from the disk and restart the service.

Comment: its running on synology, which as far as I can google is a heavily modified and trimmed Debian fork!

Comment: maybe easier to just reinstall docker altogether?

Comment: I don't think it's faster to reinstall docker. Try to first restart the docker daemon, and then perform the docker rm command. If it's not working, try to stop the service remove the container from the disk: rm -r /var/lib/docker/containers/<container-id>/ (make sure the directory is ok) and then restart it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240468/discussion-between-giovanni-patruno-and-dankdoggy).

Comment: @dankdoggy, probably not in option in critical systems. If this is some dev or local machine, this may be an idea.

Comment: @GiovanniPatruno. afaik, if you restart the deamon, it should also start the container again.

Answer (score 0):

Consider restarting docker daemon. If the issue persist, try to:

- stop docker
- run a `rm -r /var/lib/docker/containers/<container-id>`
- start docker